# Removing Processing Instructions with Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using the python lxml library to transform XML files to a new schema but I've encountered problems parsing processing instructions from the XML body.

The processing instruction elements are scattered throughout the XML, as in the following example (they all begin with "oasys" and end with a unique code):

```
string = "<text><?oasys _dc21-?>Text <i>contents</i></text>"
```

I can't locate them through the `lxml.etree.findall()` method, although `etree.getchildren()` returns them:

```
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(string)
print tree.findall(".//")
>>>> [<Element i at 0x747c>]
print tree.getchildren()
>>>> [<?oasys _dc21-?>, <Element i at 0x747x>]
print tree.getchildren()[0].tag
>>>> <built-in function ProcessingInstruction>
print tree.getchildren()[0].tail
>>>> Text
```

Is there an alternative to using `getchildren()` to parse and remove processing instructions, especially considering that they're nested at various levels throughout the XML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`processing-instruction()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) XPath node test to find the processing instructions and remove them using [`etree.strip_tags()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags).

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

string = "<text><?oasys _dc21-?>Text <i>contents</i></text>"
tree = etree.fromstring(string)

pis = tree.xpath("//processing-instruction()")
for pi in pis:
    etree.strip_tags(pi.getparent(), pi.tag)

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<text>Text <i>contents</i></text>
```

Comment: You've actually solved two problems with your answer - I didn't know about the strip_tags() function but it's very useful!

Comment: This will cause an error if a parent has more than one processing instruction.  Checking that the parent is not None will fix.